# Fastest min max among three floats in C

Tags: c, floating-point, max, min

I think the question is pretty clear: I have three numbers, I  have two functions, min and max.

What are the fastest implementations?

Comment: Why do you care? Why using the naive approach is not enough for you?

Comment: Just implement them in a readable fashion, the compiler will deal with the rest. And your question is incomplete: what do you do with `NaN`s?

Comment: For so basic functions it will quite depend on the particular processor used to run them.

Comment: Thanks guys, the reason I ask is because I'm running a code at 5 kHz and I've ran out of time in an interrupt i.e. interrupt instance 'n' is interrupted by interrupt instance 'n+1'

Comment: If you are using an embedded processor without a FPU, you may be able to perform the comparisons much faster accessing the internal representation of the floats as bytes, specially if the three numbers have the same sign and NaN and other special cases don't need to be handled.

Comment: Don't know how to do that.. I do know the numbers can have different signs but can never be NaN..

Comment: Well, before going the hard way, use a disassembler to see what your compiler does with the implementation provided by Frerich Raabe bellow.

Answer (score 18):

The C standard (C99) provides the [`fmaxf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fmax.html) and [`fminf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fmin.html) functions in the standard C [math.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/math.h.html) header. I'd start by just using it to find the largest of three floats and then check whether it's fast enough for your needs:

```
float max = fmaxf(a, fmaxf(b, c));
float min = fminf(a, fminf(b, c));
```

Answer (score 5):

Naive solution is two use two comparisons to find the min and then two comparisons to find the max. This is suboptimal since three comparisons suffice (pseudocode returning (min, max) tuple follows):

```
function minmax(float a, float b, float c): (float, float)
begin
  boolean altb = (a < b);
  boolean bltc = (b < c);
  if altb and bltc then return (a, c);
  if not altb and not bltc then return (c, a);
  if altb then // Also: c <= b, so b is known to be max
  begin
    if a < c then return (a, b);
    return (c, b);
  end
  if bltc then // Also: b <= a, so b is known to be min
  begin
    if a < c then return (b, c);
    return (b, a);
  end
  // Unreachable.
end
```

(This is written to be most readable, rather than to minimize the branch count)

This performs between 2 and 3 comparisons. It is impossible to use only 2 comparisons since there are 3! = 6 reorderings of 3 floats and 2 comparisons can only differentiate between 4 different ones. This is easily seen on a decision tree of the problem.

In practice one should rely for optimizations like this one on the compiler.

Comment: +1 from me (don't get why somebody else gave this -1) for trying to minimize the number of comparisons.

Comment: @Frerich Raabe: In modern processors comparisons are not slower than any other operation. Branches and dependencies are usually the problem, though the optimizer may take care of all of that (I wasn't the downvoter!)

Comment: I am not the downvoter either, but it probably would be nicer if your answer would be C.

Answer (score 2):

Code to find the greatest of three numbers.

```
#includ<stdio.h>

void main()

{
    float a,b,c;
    printf("enter a,b,c:");
    scanf("%f%f%f",&a,&b,&c); 
    printf("Greatest no: %f"(a>b)?((a>c)?a:c):((c>b)?c:b)); 
}
```

Reverse the logic to find the least :)

Answer (score 2):

I liked Adam Zalcman's approach so much, I rewrote it in C, this time minimising branches too (so at most 3 comparisons and 3 branches).

```
struct Pair
{
    float min_value;
    float max_value;
};

struct Pair minmax(float a, float b, float c)
{
    /* truth table:
     * a<b b<c a<c
     *  T   T   *  => (a, c)
     *  T   F   T  => (a, b)
     *  T   F   F  => (c, b)
     *  F   T   T  => (b, c)
     *  F   T   F  => (b, a)      
     *  F   F   *  => (c, a)
     */
    if (a < b) {
        if (b < c) 
            return (struct Pair) {a, c};
        else {
            if (a < c)
                return (struct Pair) {a, b};
            else
                return (struct Pair) {c, b};
        }
    } else {
        if (b < c) {
            if (a < c)
                return (struct Pair) {b, c};
            else
                return (struct Pair) {b, a};
        } else
            return (struct Pair) {c, a};
    }
}

void foo()
{
    struct Pair result = minmax(1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
}
```

(this may be degenerating into code golf now though ...)

Comment: It's not beautiful, but a reason for the downvote might be informative.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but my guess is because the submitter wants two separate function implementations (max and min) and not a single function that returns both.